Star Citizen build for casual gamer 1080p
I used to be in the master race when I was young, then life happened, but today I'm giving myself a little treat and trying to catch up with the enormous tech advancements since the old days.
My aim is to play Star Citizen (and Kerbal Space Program but I doubt it's the worst case!), and I don't want to spend too much (my car is getting very old, it will have priority...) - I don't play much, I'm just sick and tired of lags in the few games that really draw me in and it's about time I bask in the beauty of Space from my chair. I only play in 1080p.
My last PC cost me 1200USD and it was a so-called gaming laptop 7 years ago. I have an absolute max of 1500USD today with tax (2000CAD, I'm in Canada), I thought I'd be able to do 1500CAD with tax but my hopes are being shattered.
My current build is here: https://ca.pcpartpicker.com/list/T3wsRK
Would you mind taking a look and telling me if I'm making the right choices? I'm already at my absolute max budget but perhaps there is cheaper or smarter.
P.S: If the PC is able to allow linking to my Oculus Quest 2, that'd be great.

One small comment I have is that the SSD you chose comes with a heat sink but the motherboard already has a built-in heat sink over the main M.2 slot. You can probably save a few dollars getting the version of the Crucial SSD without the heat sink.

You can also probably save quite a bit of money (up to $60 CAD) on the case if you don't mind getting something ultra cheap. A nice case is really worth that money but if you're trying to squeeze the most value out and don't care about how it looks then there are far cheaper options for cases.

I also have to point out that you should absolutely not cut back on the 32GB of RAM for Star Citizen, the game truly uses over 26 GB of RAM so 16GB kits would lead to heavy pagefile usage which makes the game stutter and wears down your SSD.

Also make sure your monitor has HDMI or Displayport, since the GPUs don't use DVI these days.

Excellent points, thanks @Romen! I currently have a pack of 2x 16GB RAM sticks, do you mean I should get a single 32GB stick? I don't think it makes a difference but maybe I'm wrong. Also I hesitated a lot between 13600KF and 5700X3D, do you think I made the right call?

I've made an alternative build using the 13600KF and DDR5 instead, the price is even higher but not by much (+50USD) so I can go this route if it's better investment: https://ca.pcpartpicker.com/list/XJHCsh

I just mean your total RAM should be more than 16GB because the game on its own uses way more than that. 32GB is usually enough but I have even seen the game use more than 32GB whenever there's a patch that has memory leaks.

Would you be down to go with used parts? You can get a little more bang for the buck
